# ng-src requires a non-empty src attribute on img tag

Tags: angularjs

The documentation for `ng-src` [shows that using ng-src by itself should work](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSrc). However, when I try to use it on my image, the image doesn't show up unless I have a `src` attribute specified with some text.

The following does not work:

```
<img ng-src="{{img.url}}" />
```

The following works:

```
<img src="placeholder_text" ng-src="{{img.url}}" />
```

Comment: `img.url` is just the url pulled from a data source. I know that `img.url` works as it works when I include the `src` attribute.
What is a plunker?

Comment: Which browser are you using?

Comment: @rar: What version of Angular are you using ?

Comment: @rar: It seems to work fine: http://plnkr.co/edit/xf3UwNgTBhTo5ZN075BC?p=preview

Answer (score -1):

Try just

```
{{img}}
```

instead of

```
{{img.url}}
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/Z55CZxaEx92XztKP8Nhn?p=preview

When the HTML is loading, the ngSrc directive should create a src attribute with the URL of the ng-src attribute. From the plnkr example:

INPUT HTML:

```
<img ng-src="{{img}}" />
```

JS:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
  $scope.img = 'http://mawords.com/images/plnkr.co.gif';
});
```

OUTPUT HTML

```
<img ng-src="http://mawords.com/images/plnkr.co.gif" src="http://mawords.com/images/plnkr.co.gif">
```